# Arrange the following functions

Tags: algorithms

Arrange the following functions into increasing order

(lgn^3) , 2^lgn ,4^lgn , 4n lg n + 2n , (n^2/3)

I am confused which function is the smaller function and whether

- (lgn^3) is considered cubic or logarithmic ?
- 4n lg n + 2 is considered n log n ?
- 2^lgn is considered Exponential ?
- (n^2/3) is considered linear ?

please help. thanks

Comment: Are your functions $\log(n^3)$,$2^{\log(n)}$,$4^{\log(n)}+2n$ and $n^{\frac{2}{3}}$ ?

Comment: yes it is. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The logarithm function is an increasing function. (As $n$ increases, so does $\log n$.)

$\log(n^3) = 3\log n$.

$4^{\log n} = (2^2)^{\log n} = 2^{2\log n} > 2^{\log n}$

$n^{2/3}$ is **not** linear.

Suggestion: **Graph** the functions.